# Set php7 location to Apache (Macports)

Tags: apache, macports, php-7

I've installed php7 via MacPorts to the El Capitan using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JMuQFLA_KM).
Is it possible to execute php7 with default OSX Apache (not Apache from MacPorts)? If yes, where should I set php7 location in Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone had the same problem, [this tutorial](https://medium.com/enekochan/install-php-7-0-in-mac-os-x-with-macports-e21b92954732) helped to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts will build all modules only for the Apache httpd provided by MacPorts itself and not for the system version.

See the notes for the php70-apache2handler port how you can enable the module:

```
$ port notes php70-apache2handler
php70-apache2handler has the following notes:
  If this is your first install, you need to enable php70-apache2handler in your web server.
  To enable php70-apache2handler, run:

      cd /opt/local/apache2/modules
      sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/apxs -a -e -n php7 mod_php70.so
```